# Upgraded from Spring 4.1.6 to 4.2.4 and suddenly getting TransactionRequiredException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-ws, spring-transactions

I have upgraded to latest Spring version from 4.1.6.Release to 4.2.4.Release and suddenly all what has functioned smoothly before, now throws the following exception.

```
 javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:277) ~[na:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Interceptor.class

```
public class MessageInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {

    @Resource
    private SaveMessageDO saveMessageDO;

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) {
     saveMessageDO.addMessage(messageContext.getRequest()));        
     return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) {

    }
}


SaveMessageDO.class
    /**
     * The entity manager.
     */
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxxHibernatePersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    /**
     * Adds the message.
     *
     * @param message the message
     */
    @Transactional(value = "xyzTxManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addMessage(final Message message) {
        entityManager.persist(message);
    }
```

Exception occurs in SharedEntityManagerCreator.java

```
else if (transactionRequiringMethods.contains(method.getName())) {
                    // We need a transactional target now, according to the JPA spec.
                    // Otherwise, the operation would get accepted but remain unflushed...
                    if (target == null || !TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
                        throw new TransactionRequiredException("No EntityManager with actual transaction available " +
                                "for current thread - cannot reliably process '" + method.getName() + "' call");
                    }
                }
```

The method are marked with @Transaction Annotation, when i call switch back to older spring version its works fine without any issues.

Bit Background about the code, calling from Spring Webservices Interceptors to store SOAP Message in database.

Comment: I think we will need a bit more background. :)

Comment: @Basco, We want to save the messages in the database before we post in queue and in the interceptors we wrote to intercept the message and store in the database. Added more code for understanding

Comment: You need to include the configuration for you transactions in your `applicationContext.xml` as well as what server you are using (_i.e. JBoss (aka WildFly)_)

Answer (score 4):

Try upgrading your version to 4.2.4 announced here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/17/spring-framework-4-2-4-4-1-9-released

> 4.2.4 addresses a few regressions in the 4.2.x line and includes many
>   fixes and enhancements, with no immediate issues remaining. 4.2.4 is a
>   recommended upgrade for all 4.x users now.

I think the problem your experiencing is possibly related to this question:  [Inconsistent JPA behavior using no transaction, propagation SUPPORTS and OpenEntityManager pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27346975/539394) and this bug report https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13243

And in anyway, if it isn't the new version may still resolve your problem as many issues and regressions were fixed.

When getting unexpected issues that could be attributed to a framework it's always a good idea to check for any fix releases and to check their bug management system as well e.g. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13243?jql=project%20%3D%20SPR%20AND%20text%20~%20transactionrequiredexception

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Updated with Latest Spring Version 4.2.4.Release. It doesnt help. I think somebody already issue : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13838. I think my issue also related to that. Spring commited to fix this issue in 4.2.5

Comment: @SathishMurugesan Good to hear it's in progress. If the issue turns out to be fixed in 4.2.5 please let us know and self-answer? :)