# Migration from spring 3.2 to 4.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I am getting the same exact issue as mentioned in the link below :

[Upgraded from Spring 4.1.6 to 4.2.4 and suddenly getting TransactionRequiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494754/upgraded-from-spring-4-1-6-to-4-2-4-and-suddenly-getting-transactionrequiredexce/44683837?noredirect=1#comment76351833_44683837)

For me too the target is null in the SharedEntityManagerCreator.java.

I have a similar setup for configuration and @transactional annnotation. I looked at the spring jira ticket given in the above link.

In my case in the TransactionSynchronizationManager ( lines shown below ). The call to resources.get() returns a null map.

```
private static Object doGetResource(Object actualKey) {
    Map<Object, Object> map = resources.get();
    if (map == null) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my hibernate xml configuration :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycomp"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="persistenceUnitName">xxxxPersistenceUnitName</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">xxxxPostgreSQLDialectWithHStore</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">phoenix</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**ADDING MORE INFO**

High Level Structure

```
   WebService Endpoint 
        Services Components
            Persistent Service
```

My Persistent Service Class `public interface xxxService{

```
@Transactional
public <T> T update(T entity);
```

}

@Componen
public class xxxxServiceImpl implements xxxService{

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxxx")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public <T> T update(T entity) {
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

}`

I have tried to put the @Transactional annotation in the class level but gives me same error. 
Also when i debug Spring does not create proxy for My persistence class which it should as the transactional annotation is on that class. Instead it creates it on the EntityManager. ( I am not sure why this behaviour but thats what i observed. )

My Technology stack if it is helpful :

1. Migration from java 7 to java 8
2. Migration from spring 3.2 to Spring 4.3
3. Migration from hibernate 4.1 to 5.2.10

I do see following log in the log files :

SVCS 2017-06-29 12:34:06,942 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'scopedTarget.xxxxService' of type [com.xxxxx.database.xxxxxService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

NOT sure if they are relevent but it shows the Service which has entityManager defined it say ( not eligible for auto-proxying ) not sure if this is what causing the issue.

Comment: Anyone able to figure out what is wrong with my code or configuration ?